# Reverse "mobile-phone" and "cellphone" tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Currently, [cellphones](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellphones) is the primary topic, with [mobile-phone](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-phone) (as well as [iphone](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone) and [simcard](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcard)) as synonyms. I propose that [mobile-phones](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-phones) should be the primary term instead.

The device has many names in different parts of the world: *cell phone*, *cellular phone*, *cell*, *handphone*, *handy*, *mobile phone*, *mobile*, *portable*, and so on. On the other hand,

- *cellphone* refers to cellular technology, and is not technically accurate for satellite phones or portable IP phones. It is still the primary term in North America but is no longer elsewhere (even in Latin America, *telefonía móvil* seems to be displacing *telefonía celular*).
- *handphone* is the standard term in East and Southeast Asia, but does not seem to be common in English-speaking countries elsewhere.
- the abbreviations like *cell* or *handy* are too ambiguous to be useful tags.

On the other hand, I think the term *mobile phone* is clear and well-understood. It is the common usage in Europe, but also the more universal-- you'll find cellphone and mobile or handphone and mobile used together, but quite rarely cellphone and handphone. And for the pedants, it would cover both satellite and cellular phones and any other mobile technology we may devise moving forward.

Comment: I was sure I'd brought up the same topic about a year ago but I can't find it here in meta so it must've been in chat. Anyway I wholeheartedly agree.

Comment: By the way, I feel the same about [tag:automobiles] and [tag:cars].

Comment: I agree as well - cell phone is nowhere near as well understood outside the US, so it would make sense to go with the one more globally acceptable.

Answer (score -2):

My understanding is that even though 'cellphone' is not a primary term *everywhere* in the world, people *do* understand it everywhere that it can be used interchangeably with 'mobile phone' or 'handphone'. As long as the tag wiki excerpt and synonyms are unambiguous, I don't see a need to change.